# No informix tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Just asked an informix question here, couldn't tag it as such since the tag doesn't exist (and I don't have enough reputation to create it).

Granted, there aren't many Informix questions here, but I would still think the tag should exist (as it does on Stackoverflow).

Comment: It does belong on the site, and thanks for sharing this information. You came to the right place to inform us.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've created one for you.

Cheers